# Tennis Grand Slam winner who didn't lose a set

Tags: trivia, tennis, history, grand-slam

Rafael Nadal "The King of Clay" won the [2017 French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles) dominantly without dropping a set. He got a little bit of help achieving the feat as he didn't face either of the top 2 ranking players (i.e., a combination of remarkable skills on his favorite surface and a bit of luck).

This makes me wonder how many times this has happened before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the difficulty this event had already occurred several times in the past: 9 times for men events and 40 times in women events in modern era.

**men records for modern era:**

- Bjorn Borg and Rafael Nadal take this achievement 3 times each
- Bjorn Borg in [1976 Wimbledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_Wimbledon_Championships) and Rafael Nadal in [2017 Roland Garros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_French_Open) were the lowest ranking (4th) player to win a Grand Slam witouht losing a set
- AUS open: 2 times
- Roland Garros: 6 times
- Wimbledon: 2 times
- US open: never happened

**women records for modern era:**

- women: Martina Navratilova and Serena Williams won a Grand Slam tournaments witouh losing a set 6 times each
- the lowest ranking player to win a Grand Slam without losing a set was n.15th Marion Bartoli in [2013 Wimbledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_Singles) (her only Gran Slam tiltle just before her retirement)
- AUS open: 8 times
- Roland Garros: 7 times
- Wimbledon: 10 times
- US open: 15 times

[Here the updated wikipedia pages with the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Grand_Slam_related_tennis_records#Won_a_title_without_losing_a_set)

It is interesting to notice that for Nadal this 2017 Roland Garros represents his personal career record for percentage of game won on game losts (116 GW vs only 35 GL => 76.8%)